# Facebook ad statistics - can't get facebook keyword stats

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api, adgroup, keywordstats

I have created a campaign, specified the interests in the ad and successfully executed the campaign which lasted 2 days. I have got around 9 website clicks and the reach was approximately 35000. I am trying to retrieve keyword stats through api but I am getting empty json object. I followed [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-keyword-stats/) link.
Here is the cURL command:

```
url -G -d "access_token=abcd" "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.7/ad_id/keywordstats"
```

And here is the result:

```
{"data":[]}
```

Why am I getting empty json object. Where am I going wrong? I need some assistance.

Comment: What permissions does your access token include? // Suggest you use [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) for testing such stuff, easier to use & gives debug info (about stuff such as missing permissions.)

Comment: I tested it using Graph API Explorer, still it gives empty json object. How do I check permissions?

Comment: I went through details and here are the scopes defined for the account. ads_management, ads_read, read_insights, business_management, public_profile

Comment: Are you sure there should be a response there? That API only returns values for ads which use interest targeting and which were active in the last 7 days

Comment: The result appears now. I didn't modified anything. May be after the campaign is executed completely then after some days the keywords are available. That's what happened in my case. I have scheduled another test campaign, I will check it again. Then update

Answer (score 0):

The **keywordstats** api only show the breakdown statistics for the ads that resulted in enough stats. In case some interests haven't resulted in any stats, they won't be included in the breakdown statistics .

As a rule of thumb, there is an average delay of **24 hours** (before the stats are available). However, we've noticed that it can be less or more as well. Only Facebook will know the exact logic behind that.